# Can't plot some messages types on rqt_plot

Tags: ros-hydro, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to plot some messages but this warning appears at executing rqt_plot:

```
TopicCompleter.update_topics(): could not get message class for topic type "atlas_msgs/ForceTorqueSensors" on topic "/atlas/force_torque_sensors"
```

and in general:

```
TopicCompleter.update_topics(): could not get message class for topic type "foo_msg" on topic "foo_topic"
```

If I execute rqt_plot with the data I want to plot (`rqt_plot /atlas/force_torque_sensors/l_foot/force/x:y:z`) this error shows up:

```
PluginHandlerDirect._restore_settings() plugin "rqt_plot/Plot#0" raised an exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/plugin_handler_direct.py", line 116, in _restore_settings
    self._plugin.restore_settings(plugin_settings_plugin, instance_settings_plugin)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_plot/plot.py", line 172, in restore_settings
    self._switch_data_plot_widget(int(instance_settings.value('plot_type', 0)))
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_plot/plot.py", line 162, in _switch_data_plot_widget
    self._widget.switch_data_plot_widget(selected_plot['widget_class'](self._widget))
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_plot/plot_widget.py", line 98, in switch_data_plot_widget
    self.add_topic(topic_name)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_plot/plot_widget.py", line 193, in add_topic
    self._rosdata[topic_name] = ROSData(topic_name, self._start_time)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_plot/rosplot.py", line 114, in __init__
    self.sub = rospy.Subscriber(real_topic, data_class, self._ros_cb)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 502, in __init__
    super(Subscriber, self).__init__(name, data_class, Registration.SUB)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 135, in __init__
    raise ValueError("topic parameter 'data_class' is not initialized")
ValueError: topic parameter 'data_class' is not initialized
```

Someone can help me with this? I can plot data over some topics, so, Is there something that I have to do before?

I'm using Hydro and Ubuntu 12.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72739/can%27t-plot-some-messages-types-on-rqt_plot/) by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 756 on 2013-08-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-08-14**:
What happens if you do the following? 1) run `$ rqt --clear-config` 2) choose Plot from `Plugins` tab 3) Type in the topic name ?

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-08-14**:
See answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, Today I turned on the computer and without try to run rqt_plot again, I installed ros-hydro-rqt-msg, then run rqt and choose Plot and it works.

After this I run `rqt_plot /atlas/force_torque_sensors/l_foot/force/x:y:z` and also works... so I'm not sure what fix the issue, if rebooting or installing rqt-msg.

---

Originally posted by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) with karma: 756 on 2013-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-08-14**:
That's strange. `rqt_plot` doesn't depend on `_msg` at all. If you like, can you try uninstall ros-hydro-rqt-msg and try?

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-08-14**:
Ok.. i will try it later. I have to install all the stuff in another machine in the next few days, then I will tell you how this will going.

**Comment by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on 2016-12-11**:
This does not work for me :( I tried to do

```
rqt_plot /apriltag2_tag_detections/detections/pose/pose/position/x:y:z
```

But it does not plot anything.